# Active Directory logon issue

Tags: active-directory

I have created one Active directory and consist of some users. But when the user are trying to login through their machine, they are getting an error:

> The security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship.

Why it is getting, I don't know?  Please help me out of it.

Comment: Rejoin the PC to the domain

Answer (score 0):

I've had this several times as well.

Give your computer a custom computer name: Like 'TEMP_PCNAME' and remove it from the domain, so add it to the Workgroup again.

Reboot and re-join to the domain.

Make sure you clean-up the Computers-list on AD-site.

Comment: Please mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way I've reestablished the domain trust is to enter the NetBIOS name instead of the FQDN.